# How to edit a remote desktop connection on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-explorer, remote-desktop, windows-11, context-menu

I've recently "upgraded" from Windows 10 to Windows 11.

On Windows 10 I could right-click on a RDP file and there's an "edit" option on the context menu, but that's gone on Windows 11. There is a "show more options" but this just crashes Explorer.

I've tried to uninstall and reinstall the RDP client but it seems it's built-in and there's no way to do this.

Does anyone know how I can get this functionality back on Windows 11?

----- edit 11 October ----

the "show more options" is working again for me after a Windows update this morning.

I've also realised that the right-click menu on windows 11 is broken by design but you can get back the correct context menu with a registry hack

https://www.elevenforum.com/t/disable-show-more-options-context-menu-in-windows-11.1589/

Comment: You should first fix the "show more options" crash before doing anything, because the Edit option may perhaps be in it already. Start by testing Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). When all is clean, see this [article](https://windowsreport.com/windows-11-right-click-show-all-options/).

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I noticed 7-zip has disappeared as well so I guess they have changed the way context menus work in W11

Comment: Microsoft has decided to stash all the "confusing" stuff inside "show more options". Supposedly this will improve our experience ...

Comment: @Andy did the workaround from my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Try to work around this, you can manually edit RDP files using a text editor like Notepad. Here's how:

- Locate the RDP file you want to edit.
- Right-click on it and choose "Open with" and then select "Notepad" or another text editor of your choice.
- Edit the RDP file as needed.
- Save the changes.This method allows you to manually modify the RDP settings within the file.
  Just be cautious when making changes, as incorrect modifications can affect the functionality of your RDP connections.

Answer (score 2):

Hold down the Shift key when right-clicking the RDP-file. That should give you the old style context menu including the "edit" entry.

Unless this will crash your explorer as well, in this case I would either follow harrymc's advice or create a new question.

Comment: unfortunately this crashed explorer as well, though now my "show more options" is working this also works and is a useful tip for anyone who doesn't want to use the registry hack to completely remove "show more options".

Comment: @Andy Thanks, good to know, it seems to have been a bug caused by the old-style menu. Good thing the update fixed it.

Comment: @Andy I would appreciate an upvote if you find the shortcut helpful but of course, that's totally up to you.